# where to place htaccess file on openshift for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, openshift, paas

I have read and tried these previous questions on Stack Overflow networks,
these solutions doesn't solved my confusion. So I am asking the same question again.

The questions that I've researched and doesn't solve my problem 
 
[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784892/wordpress-htaccess-on-red-hat-openshift-pass) 
[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170281/where-to-put-wordpress-htaccess-on-openshift)
 
[Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27210756/htaccess-seemingly-ignored-on-openshift)
[Question 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27202410/openshift-and-redirect-in-htaccess)
[Question 5](https://serverfault.com/questions/618655/where-to-put-wordpress-htaccess-on-openshift)
[Question 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234289/verify-if-htaccess-file-is-running)

I'm just trying to install WordPress on OpenShift by custom way than the one click install. I've cloned my openshift git repo on my desktop. Extracted, added and pushed wordpress.tar.gz to the repo and installed correctly so that i could login to the admin site.

my repo files look this way,

```
deena@home:~/Desktop/wordpress$ ls -al
total 76
drwxrwxr-x  7 deena deena 4096 Feb  4 23:20 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 deena deena 4096 Feb  6 22:11 ..
drwxrwxr-x  8 deena deena 4096 Feb  4 23:20 .git
-rw-rw-r--  1 deena deena    9 Feb  4 16:41 .gitignore
drwxrwxr-x  2 deena deena 4096 Feb  4 16:41 libs
drwxrwxr-x  2 deena deena 4096 Feb  4 16:41 misc
drwxrwxr-x  9 deena deena 4096 Feb  4 16:41 .openshift
drwxrwxr-x  2 deena deena 4096 Feb  4 16:41 php
-rw-rw-r--  1 deena deena 2130 Feb  4 16:41 README
```

I want to put the *.htaccess* file on this repo so that wordpress can use this in some RW mode. Where can I place the htaccess?

one man said on the listed question to place it on the config directory then action_hook to use it on the base directory, 
where's the config directory? should I do any hard work to make it work? (I don't know whats action_hook honestly)
some questions were answered to place it on the base dir, that's the listed dir, some other said to place it in the app directory, the wordpress directory seen here.
I tried placing in the base as well as the app directory nothing happens other than the wordpress is reinstalled the next time I point my browser to the app URL.

**So making the question clear again, in layman terms, where to place the htaccess file to make it accessible for WordPress?** 
thanks.

peace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The .htaccess files needs to go in the same directory as your core WordPress files, wherever your wp-config.php file is.  However, since you are deploying this site via git, with all of the WordPress files included, whatever changes that are made to the .htaccess file by WordPress will be reverted once you do another git push.  If you don't plan on doing any more git pushes, then everything should be fine.  The same thing goes with any of the plugins or themes, they will be removed on a git push if you install them using the WordPress admin interface.  You will either need to make your changes locally in your git repo on your workstation (adding themes, adding plugins, updating .htaccess), or you will need to use a quickstart that uses symlinks to store that information on the server in a different location.  You could also use the WordPress OpenShift quickstart which is designed just for use with OpenShift, and helps you with a lot of these issues....

Answer (score 1):

I think, [here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/why-you-cant-find-htaccess-file-on-your-wordpress-site/) you can find a solution.

Comment: I don't think this answer needs a +1.

Comment: @deena agree, I'll update my answer with further explanation